# Docker: How can I execute 2 scripts one after the another using DockerFile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile, I want to run 2 scripts.

I want once the first script ran successfully then only it will run another script because another script is consuming the output of the first script.

What changes do I need to make in Dockerfile to complete this task?

```
FROM ubuntu

WORKDIR /usr/bin/

COPY ./example.py .

RUN chmod +x example.py

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "example.py"]
```

I want to include one move ENTRYPOINT to execute another script.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What does your Dockerfile look like currently?

Comment: Please check, I have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Command chaining `&&` will help. Reference `Dockerfile` considering you have scripts placed under `scripts` folder on your system.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY ./scripts /scripts 
WORKDIR /scripts
RUN chmod +x /scripts/script-1.sh && chmod +x /scripts/script-2.sh
RUN /scripts/script-1.sh && /scripts/script-2.sh
```